# Zookeer is part of hadoop or separate configuration?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, bigdata

As I read from various tuts, zookeeper helps to coordinate and sync various hadoop clusters.

Currently I installed hadoop 2.5.0. When I do jps it displays

```
4494 SecondaryNameNode
8683 Jps
4679 ResourceManager
3921 NameNode
4174 DataNode
4943 NodeManager
```

no process for zookeeper.

I had doubt whether zookeeper is part of hdfs or we need to install it manually?

Answer (score 1):

If you use hadoop only, zookeeper is not required! for other tools in hadoop, i.e. hbase, it depends on zookeeper! but you don't need install it dedicatedly, hbase has included it, if you startup hbase, the zookeeper will startup at the same time.